# how do i eliminate duplicates records in sql using inner join sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Went through the post is here, but still I'm unable to do the same. please any one have some idea please share me.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    TR.Id as Travel_RequestId,
    TREP.FirstName+' '+TREP.LastName as [Traveler Name],
    TR.EmployeeNo,
    TR.RequestNO,
    TravelType=(case TR.IsOneWay
    when '1' THEN 'OW'
    ELSE 'RT'
    END),
    TRPD.SWONCode,
    cast(TRD.GESSReceivedDate as date) as GESSReceivedDate,
    TRD.Deal,
    TRD.AirLineCode,
    cast(TRD.DepartureDate as date) as Departure_Date,
    cast(TRD.TentativeReturnDate as date) as Tentative_Return_Date,
    cast(TRTD.IssuanceDate as Date) as Tcket_IssuanceDate,
    TRTD.DeskName,
    (select Description from AirlineName where Code=TRD.AirlineNameCode) as Airline,
    (select Description from Currency where Code=TRID.CurrencyTypeCode) as CurrencyType,
    case when (isnumeric(TRTD.BaseFare) & isnumeric(TRTD.ServiceFee)) =1 then 
    (convert(float, TRTD.BaseFare)+convert(float, TRTD.ServiceFee))
    else 
    null 
    end as TicketAmount,
    TRTD.Number As [Ticket Number],
    TRTD.AgentName,
    cast(TRID.IssueDate as date ) As InvoiceDate,
    cast(TRID.CreditNoteDate as date) as CreditNoteDate,
    TRID.CreditNoteNumber,
    TRID.CreditNoteAmount,
    TRID.AmountPayable,
    TRTD.TotalFare,
    TRTD.DeskName,
    TRID.InvoiceAmount,
    TRID.InvoiceNumber,
    TRID.CurrencyTypeCode,
    TRID.AdcolAmount,
    TRID.ChqNo,
    TM.Description as Travel_Mode,

    TRID.Statement,

    TRD.Sector As Itineary,
    TRD.ServiceClass As ClassOfTravel

    from TravelRequest TR LEFT JOIN(SELECT mt.*    
    FROM TravelRequestDetails mt INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT travelrequestId, MIN(DepartureDate) DepartureDate
    FROM TravelRequestDetails
    GROUP BY travelrequestId
) t ON mt.travelrequestId = t.travelrequestId AND mt.DepartureDate = t.DepartureDate)TRD ON TRD.TravelRequestId =TR.Id 

     left join TravelRequestEmployeeProfile TREP 
    on TREP.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    left join TravelRequestProjectDetails TRPD 
    on TRPD.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    left join TravelMode TM 
    on TM.Code=TRPD.TravelModeCode 
    left join TravelRequestTicketDetails TRTD 
    on TRTD.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    left join TravelRequestInvoiceDetails TRID
    on TRID.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    where TR.Status='CL' and TR.RequestType='BT'
     and TR.UpdatedOn Between DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) + '18:01'
             AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '18:00' order by [Traveler Name]
```

I'm getting the below o/p where i need to remove the null records:
[image]

Below is the screen shot and i need to remove the duplication based on request no in highlighted row

Comment: those rows were not duplicate. Request no is same but other information is different

Comment: you need to add your full requirements to the question, and maybe the structures of the tables you are joining on.

Comment: Please read this?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  By doing some work yourself to isolate the problem and find a *minimal* example, you may solve it yourself, and find you're learning yourself in the process.  Even if you don't, you'll have a much cleaner question and get better answers from here.

Comment: wow ... learn to format.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so SQL is doing what you're telling it to do and removing the duplicate rows of data. What you want it to do however is return duplicates only based upon the ID.

You'll have to check whether this is going to work with your data, but in your outer select you could change everything that isn't ID to an aggregate. If you were to do a MAX on all other columns and then GROUP BY the ID field, you'll end up with one row for each ID and the highest value from the remaining columns. In the data supplied this would give you what you're after but, again, please check with your full data set to see if this is giving you the correct results before pushing the code live.

Answer (score 0):

If each `Travel_RequestId` should have only record you can use `group by`

```
with cte as 
( SELECT DISTINCT 
    TR.Id as Travel_RequestId,
    TREP.FirstName+' '+TREP.LastName as [Traveler Name],
    TR.EmployeeNo,
    TR.RequestNO,
    TravelType=(case TR.IsOneWay
    when '1' THEN 'OW'
    ELSE 'RT'
    END),
    TRPD.SWONCode,
    cast(TRD.GESSReceivedDate as date) as GESSReceivedDate,
    TRD.Deal,
    TRD.AirLineCode,
    cast(TRD.DepartureDate as date) as Departure_Date,
    cast(TRD.TentativeReturnDate as date) as Tentative_Return_Date,
    cast(TRTD.IssuanceDate as Date) as Tcket_IssuanceDate,
    TRTD.DeskName,
    (select Description from AirlineName where Code=TRD.AirlineNameCode) as Airline,
    (select Description from Currency where Code=TRID.CurrencyTypeCode) as CurrencyType,
    case when (isnumeric(TRTD.BaseFare) & isnumeric(TRTD.ServiceFee)) =1 then 
    (convert(float, TRTD.BaseFare)+convert(float, TRTD.ServiceFee))
    else 
    null 
    end as TicketAmount,
    TRTD.Number As [Ticket Number],
    TRTD.AgentName,
    cast(TRID.IssueDate as date ) As InvoiceDate,
    cast(TRID.CreditNoteDate as date) as CreditNoteDate,
    TRID.CreditNoteNumber,
    TRID.CreditNoteAmount,
    TRID.AmountPayable,
    TRTD.TotalFare,
    TRTD.DeskName,
    TRID.InvoiceAmount,
    TRID.InvoiceNumber,
    TRID.CurrencyTypeCode,
    TRID.AdcolAmount,
    TRID.ChqNo,
    TM.Description as Travel_Mode,

    TRID.Statement,

    TRD.Sector As Itineary,
    TRD.ServiceClass As ClassOfTravel

    from TravelRequest TR LEFT JOIN(SELECT mt.*    
    FROM TravelRequestDetails mt INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT travelrequestId, MIN(DepartureDate) DepartureDate
    FROM TravelRequestDetails
    GROUP BY travelrequestId
) t ON mt.travelrequestId = t.travelrequestId AND mt.DepartureDate = t.DepartureDate)TRD ON TRD.TravelRequestId =TR.Id 

     left join TravelRequestEmployeeProfile TREP 
    on TREP.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    left join TravelRequestProjectDetails TRPD 
    on TRPD.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    left join TravelMode TM 
    on TM.Code=TRPD.TravelModeCode 
    left join TravelRequestTicketDetails TRTD 
    on TRTD.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    left join TravelRequestInvoiceDetails TRID
    on TRID.TravelRequestId=TRD.TravelRequestId
    where TR.Status='CL' and TR.RequestType='BT'
     and TR.UpdatedOn Between DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) + '18:01'
             AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '18:00'
)

select Travel_RequestId, max ([Traveler Name]) as [Traveler Name], max (EmployeeNo) as EmployeeNo, max (RequestNO) as RequestNO, 
max (TravelType) as TravelType, max(SWONCode) as SWONCode /* and other columns */
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with help of `Partition By` and `row_number()`

**Example:**

`select row_number() over (partition by customerId order by orderId)
 as rowNum, customerId,Name,number over (partition by customerId order by orderId)
from Orders where rowNum=1`

Ref [Group by vs partition by](http://bugterminator.blogspot.in/2016/04/group-by-vs-partition-by.html)
.

**Edited**

In your query something like

`select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by TR.RequestNOorder by TRD.DepartureDate)
as rowNum, TR.RequestNOorder,min(TR.DepartureDate) over (partition by TR.RequestNOorder) as DepartureDate
from TravelRequestDetails where rowNum=1`

Comment: for example if i use row_number() like below its give error saying rownumber not defined.  ex:SELECT row_number() over (partition by TR.RequestNO order by TRD.DepartureDate) as rownum, columns,columns inner join conditions and rownum=1